# How to force the output to be in terms of a specific function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have a rectangular function `rect[t]`, which is a window function with values of $ 1 $ in the interval $ (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) $:-

```
rect[t_] := 1/2 (Sign[1/2 - t] + Sign[1/2 + t]);
```

Now I have some functions (most of them are terms being involved in the Fourier transformation) to be simplified, and I want the output to be in terms of `rect[t]`.

For example, I have this to be simplified

```
1/2 (-Sign[1/2 + (2 - t)/2] - Sign[1/2 + 1/2 (-2 + t)]) + 1/2 (Sign[1/2 - t/10] + Sign[1/2 + t/10])
```

I want `rect[(t - 4)/2] + rect[(t + 2)/6]` as output. What should I do?

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess you don't know about `UnitBox[]` yet? Or `HeavisidePi[]`, for that matter.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of `UnitBox[]` and `HeavisidePi[]`. But my question remains: how can I get `HeavisidePi[(t - 4)/2] + HeavisidePi[(t + 2)/6]` (or `UnitBox`) as output?